# Apache-wicket migration to new Version from 1.4.9 to 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I am using wicket 1.4.9 Now migrating to newer version 7 or 6 , But I am unable to get wicket-.6.0 / wicket-7.7.0 jar files, In mvn repository only artifact id and all given but it's not working, And even there is not Download option to copy manually into repository, I used wicket core,util,request but still getting compilation error to import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters, so any new jar thatt can be replaced wicket-1.4.9 jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `wicket-core`. If you use Maven/Gradle/... then it will download the dependencies automatically.

Then you have to update your imports. Just delete the line `import org.apache.wicket.PageParameters;` and import the class again in your IDE. If you don't use an IDE then the new package name is `org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters`

Comment: Thank you very much Martin for your response, I added wicket core and imported the required package org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters 

But now am getting problem in my code

String ticket = parameters.getString("ticket");

there is no getString() method present. there is a parameters.get(" ") of type StringValue is available , not able to cast to String value.


Below things are also i think they changed completely,

Comment: Yes, PageParameters API has evolved since 1.4.x. Now you need StringValue.toString(). It also has #toOptionalString("default"), #toInt(), #toBoolean(), etc.